# Template Content is Ignored by Solr

Tags: theming, search

We have content inside of D7 template files for pages that are heavily styled—cases where a Body field just doesn't make sense. A front-end developer writes the page like a normal HTML page, and the content goes in.

[Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) can't pick up the content on these pages though.

Our solution right now is to paste all the content on these pages in to a node's body field and hide that duplicated content, but then there's a fragmentation problem between versions. The body field doesn't go in to source control, and likewise the template's text doesn't go in to the database.

Is there a better solution to indexing content on a hard coded template? (Bonus: Is it less of an issue in D8?)

Comment: You may get away with implementing hook_apachesolr_index_document_build, reading in the template content with PHP then altering the document before it is indexed.

Comment: @cilefen Mark pointed out we're using Search Api Solr Search which doesn't have the `hook_apachesolr_index_document_build()` function

Comment: But he posted it as an answer to this question...

Comment: You have opted to store content in templates which is not how Drupal models data so you must implement something custom in order to do what you need. There is likely an equivalent hook in Search API Solr. You are going to be writing code for this one way or another.